# Animate a circle along a path curve in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui

So I am trying to create, what I thought was going to be a simple animation. I have a circle (technically a path) that fills up based on a percentage. Sort of like SwiftCharts doughnut chart. I'd like to have a ball at the end of that percentage that animates along the curve that the "chart" follows. I have seen a ton of tutorials on animating something along complex curves that involve a ton of math and figuring out complex curves, but I can't get anything to work for a simple shape to be animated along a curve and stop at the end of that curve.

What I am trying to achieve is something similar to this...
[image]

Where that circle at the end of the arc is animated from the arrow at the top, to the end position of that arc.

I can draw out the arcs and everything, but where I fall apart is just trying to get the dot to animate along that specific arc.

Here is my code to draw the arcs...

```
struct ChartView: View {
  @State var percent: Double = 0.0
  var animation: Animation {
    Animation.spring()
  }
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      Zstack {
        Path { path in
          path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width. / 2, y: geometry.size.width / 2),
            radius: geometry.size.width / 2,
            startAngle: .degrees(0),
            endAngle: .degrees(360),
            clockwise: true
          )
        }
        .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 16)
        let strokeStyle = StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 16, lineCap: .rounded)
        InnerRing(pct: self.percent)
          .stroke(Color.red, style: strokeStyle)
        Circle()
          .frame(width: 16, height: 16) //How do I add animation to this
      }
    }
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    .padding()
    .onAppear {
      withAnimation(self.animation) {
        self.percent = 0.60
      }
    }
  }
}

struct InnerRing: Shape {
  var pct: Double
  var animatableData: Double {
    get { return pct }
    set { pct = newValue }
  }
  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    let end = pct * 360
    var p = Path()
    p.addArc(
      center: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width / 2, y: rect.size.width / 2),
      radius: rect.size.width / 2,
      startAngle: .degrees(270), //to make it start at the top of the circle
      endAngle: .degrees(end - 90), //to make it fill the appropriate amount
      clockwise: false
    )
    return p
  }
}
```

So I have the path for the inner ring, and it is going to the correct place, but how do I animate that Circle along the exact same path as the InnerRing?

Sorry if the code is messy, or I have missed something, if anyone needs more info to help I'm happy to provide it. I just can't figure out how to make the circle animate along the InnerRing path.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.offset()` and `.rotationEffect` to place the circle over your path.  Set the rotation angle to `Angle(degrees: 360 * self.percent)`.

```
Circle()
    .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
    .offset(x: 0, y: -geometry.size.width / 2)
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 360 * self.percent))
```

Finally, add a `duration` to your animation to see the animation.  For example, I used `Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! This has been driving me nuts for days. I have been trying to get it to follow a path, but stop at a certain point and just could not figure it out. This worked perfectly!!!